# Become familiar OR get familiar

Tags: difference, collocations

I was wondering if you could tell me what the difference is between two verbs:

1. become familiar with
2. get familiar with

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same, but 'become' is more formal, and 'get' is less formal.

Comment: One becomes familiar with one's father-in-laws whisky preference and gets familiar with the new baby's nappy requirements.

Comment: In Victorian times, a lady would slap a man's face if he became too familiar.

Comment: Get is used more in US English.

Comment: @Peter - I think you have missed a nuance or two?